# api response laravel doesn't show

Tags: php, laravel, response

I have some problem when I want to return a value from api, when I use `dd()` function it will show the result. But when I use return, it doesn't show the result

```php
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    dd($request->user()); 
});
```

[image: when use dd()]

```php
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return response()->json($request->user());
});
```

[image: nothing to show]

Any ideas how to show it?

Comment: did you check your request method?

Comment: yes, i did. how to get the data as same as when i use dd() method?

Answer (score 1):

That is because you are returning a `GenericUser`, `Illuminate\Auth\GenericUser`, not an Eloquent Model; you are not using an Eloquent Model for the User Provider your Guard is using. This class doesn't have any means to serialize this object to JSON like a Model does and doesn't have any public properties that `json_encode` could serialize.

If you `json_encode` this object you get an empty object in JSON notation:

```
echo json_encode(new Illuminate\Auth\GenericUser(['id' => 1]));

// {}
```

Perhaps you want to be using an Eloquent Model such as `App\User` for authentication?

`config/auth.php`

```
$providers = [
    ...
    'users' => [
        'dirver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],
];
```

You are currently using the `'database'` driver for your `'users'` provider so you get a `GenericUser` to represent your user.